# Determine if nonlinear function can be positive subject to nonlinear constraints

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, inequalities

I am trying to determine if a certain nonlinear function can be positive when the variables have to satisfy multiple nonlinear constraints.

Currently my code looks like

```
FindMaximum[{f, 0 < x1 < 1, 0 < x2 < 1, 0 < x3 < 1, 0 < x4 < 1, a == 0, b > 0, c > 0},{{x1,x10},{x2,x20},{x3,x30},{x4,x40},{y1,y10},{y2,y20},{y3,y30},{y4,y40}}]
```

where `f`, `a`, `b`, and `c` depend in a nonlinear way on the `x`'s and `y`'s. (In particular, they are polynomials in the x's and trigonometric polynomials in the differences `y1 - y2`, `y2 - y3`, `y3 - y4`, and `y4 - y1`.)

My goal is to see if I can make f positive subject to the given constraints. My current approach is to run `FindMaximum` with a random initial point `{x10,x20,x30,x40,y10,y20,y30,y40}`. If `FindMaximum`, which looks for a local maximum and not a global maximum, doesn't return a positive value for f, I start over with another random initial point. I then reiterate this procedure 1000 times.

My question is if there is a better strategy for determining if `f` can be positive. (Finding the maximum of f would be nice but is not as important.) I tried to use the functions `NSolve`, `Maximize`, and `FindInstance` but they took a very long time to run, and I ended up aborting the computations.

Comment: Just based on your question, it will be hard for us to answer without providing the definition of `f`. Optimization often depends on the details of the function being optimized. An initial thought: Sometimes editing the definition is a better way to create constraints to a nonlinear optimizer than providing them explicitly because the minimizer doesn't have to monitor them or use a special constrained algorithm. For example, if you desire that `0 < x < 1`, you might be able to replace `x` with `1+Erf[x]/2`.